# Windows 7 Home Premium recovering from iSCSI target?

Tags: windows-7, iscsi

I have a notebook with Windows7 Home Premium which unable to backup to a network drive, but can use an iSCSI device. For backup... :(
But... Is there any way to restore my system from the backup was put on an iSCSI device?
If I boot the install DVD, I can recover from a USB device or (is it possible???) a network share. But what can I do with the backups on iSCSI?
I have no place for a full backup on my external HDDs, but there could be enough space on my home server.

I have an idea: make backup on iSCSI, then I connect to it a linux box, which shares it via samba. :)
(It's not a too simple solution)

Comment: I'm not sure your iSCSI device will recognized as boot device, because it need some driver to be used ..

Comment: That is the question... :) (I'm sorry, Mr. Shakespeare! :) ) At boot time, the installer can't recognize iSCSI devices, but can install drivers. Installing just iscsi driver doesn't help, because it doesn't give me cli commands to manage iscsi targets.

Comment: Hm... I've tried to create a backup onto an iSCSI disk. Windows warned: I will need a system repair disc to restore my system from this image. IMHO it's been solved.

Comment: It is very interesting... Win7 Home Premium can't make backup on a network share, but if I boot the install DVD, and select repair mode, it can access a network share, and restore previously create image from there.